# Is there a tool/jar/library/plugin which dumps riemann.io state (index) continuously into cassandra?

Tags: database, monitoring

I'm trying to implement myself some kind of riemann HA so before writing a library which persists its state into cassandra, i wanted to know if there already exist's such a library / plugin to riemann.
Is there a tool/jar/library which dumps riemann.io state (index) continuously into cassandra?